# Looping distinct values from one table through another without a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I know looping is not ideal in SQL, but I couldn't think of another way of doing this.

I want each distinct row from this Table 1 to have each distinct date and hour produced on Table 2.

In other words, Table 2 has the dates between 05/01/2014 through 04/30/2015, with each distinct date having 24 rows, one for each hour of the day. I now want each distinct row in Table 1 to have each distinct date on Table 2, with each of its 24 hours.

Table 1:

```
DROP TABLE Baylor_Raw..MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC
SELECT MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC 
INTO Baylor_Raw..MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC
FROM Baylor_Raw..Raw_ADT 
WHERE MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC IS NOT NULL AND MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC NOT IN ('#N/A','CANCEL','DAY SURGERY','HOSPICE','INFUSION')
```

Table 2:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE
SET @DATE = '05/01/2014'

DECLARE @HOUR INT
SET @HOUR = 0

DROP TABLE Baylor_Raw..DateTable
CREATE TABLE Baylor_Raw..DateTable
    (DATE_OF_DISCHARGE DATE
    ,HOUR_OF_DISCHARGE INT)


WHILE @DATE<'05/01/2015' BEGIN
    WHILE @HOUR<25 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Baylor_Raw..DateTable (DATE_OF_DISCHARGE,HOUR_OF_DISCHARGE)
        VALUES (@DATE,@HOUR)
        SET @HOUR = @HOUR+1
    END
    SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD,1,@DATE)
    SET @HOUR = 0
END
```

This below attempt did not work. I canceled after the run time exceeded several minutes.

```
DECLARE @MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC NVARCHAR(255)
SET @MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC = (SELECT MIN(MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC) FROM Baylor_Raw..MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC)

DECLARE @DATE DATE
SET @DATE = '05/01/2014'

DECLARE @HOUR INT
SET @HOUR = 0

DROP TABLE Baylor_Raw..DateTable
CREATE TABLE Baylor_Raw..DateTable
(MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC NVARCHAR,
DATE_OF_DISCHARGE DATE
,HOUR_OF_DISCHARGE INT)

WHILE @MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    WHILE @DATE<'05/01/2015' BEGIN
        WHILE @HOUR<25 BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Baylor_Raw..DateTable (MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC,DATE_OF_DISCHARGE,HOUR_OF_DISCHARGE)
            VALUES (@MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC,@DATE,@HOUR)
            SET @HOUR = @HOUR+1
        END
        SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD,1,@DATE)
        SET @HOUR = 0
    END
DELETE FROM Baylor_Raw..MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC WHERE MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC = @MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC
SET @MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC = (SELECT MIN(MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC) FROM Baylor_Raw..MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC)
SET @DATE = '05/01/2014'
END
```

Comment: I will tell you right now, I don't think you are approaching this correctly. Try explaining in words what you are trying to achieve like what are these tables for exactly? Then provide some basic input and output with sample data. I bet there is a simpler way to do this without looping.

Comment: I agree. But, I just need to create this table once which is why I figured using a loop would suffice.

Comment: Oh that's not so bad. Well, I'm glad thorsten got your question answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all distinct records from table1 paired with all records in table2? That is a cross join:

```
select *
from (select distinct * from table1) t1
cross join table2;
```

Or do you want them related by date? Then inner-join:

```
select *
from (select distinct * from table1) t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get better performance from building lists of dates and hours using loops first, and then combining it with the service names just one time using a cross join, something like this. You may need to tweak it a bit because you understand the source data:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (DATE DATE)
DECLARE @hours TABLE (hours INT)
DECLARE @hour INT
    ,@date DATE

SET @hour = 0
SET @date = '05/01/2014'

WHILE (@hour < 25)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @hours
    SELECT @hour

    SET @hour = @hour + 1
END

WHILE (@ DATE < '05/01/2015')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @dates
    SELECT @date

    SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD, 1, @DATE)
END

INSERT INTO Baylor_Raw..DateTable (
    MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC
    ,DATE_OF_DISCHARGE
    ,HOUR_OF_DISCHARGE
    )
SELECT MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC
    ,DATE
    ,hour
FROM Baylor_Raw..MEDICAL_SERVICE_DESC
CROSS JOIN @date d
CROSS JOIN @hours h
```